# How does 'Poll SCM' Jenkins feature know the repository and branch over which polling?

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, pipeline

I am configuring a legacy Jenkins which has installed the SCM Poll plugin with Git and Gerrit plugins.
Due to something I cannot comprehend, even if I have no branch or specific project configured anywhere for my git server nor in my job, I can clearly see how my job is handling the correct repository (Git Polling Log works flawlessly) and other projects don't trigger it.

Is that configured in a very hidden place? Does it work executing git on the workspace without knowing context?

I cannot see any SCM configuration tab in my Jenkins or either Fast Remote Polling or other features Im seeing appointed to in Internet, but I am using pipeline scripts, so maybe that feature is disabled, or maybe my git/gerrit plugin is infering the context somehow.

In the same section "Build Trigger", for instance, I have the Gerrit Event option disabled, and if I select the checkbox, then it asks me for a repository url and usual stuff

Comment: Was this resolved? Please share resolution or add screenshots of entire Jenkins Job configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the **Pipeline**. It has two type of definition: **Pipeline script** and **Pipeline script from SCM**. If the definition is Pipeline script from SCM, there has repo URL and branches to build.

And yes, it hasn’t  SCM configuration tab, but you can find related things in **Build Triggers** tab of **Poll SCM** selection.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't have either Git or SCM Configuration tab. Just Build triggers, and under Poll SCM only  "Schedule" cron and "Ignore post-commit hooks" checkbox is available

Comment: No, I dont find it, maybe gerrit, scm, git plugins combined produce that effect

Comment: Did you check your pipeline? There has 2 type of definition. If it’s pipeline script from SCM, there has configuration for URL and branch. If it’s pipeline script, you need to check the code which maybe defined  URL and branch.

Comment: Its script but the poll scm option is under build triggers, and it works regardless of the script